# error parsing xml file?

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

Hi all this is my first Question I create this ajax call to load xml data and append to html but my problem is not parsing xml can someone give me hand thank you ?

'XMLFile1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MyFeed Provider="FastMarkets">
  <XAUCAD name="Gold Canadian $">
    <bid_time>20140117024711</bid_time>
    <bid>1359.27</bid>
  </XAUCAD>
  <XAGCAD name="Silver Canadian $">
    <bid_time>20140117024709</bid_time>
    <bid>22.02</bid>
  </XAGCAD>
</MyFeed> 

$(function () {
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'http://localhost:52287/XMLFile1.xml',

        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
            $xml = $(xmlDoc);
            $xml.find('XAGCAD').each(function () {
                var goldBid, silverBid;
                goldBid = $(this).attr('Gold Canadian $').children('bid').text();
                alert(goldBid);
            })
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: You should also post the error message.

Comment: What error/problem are you having?

Comment: I setp throw function I find my $.parseXML(xml) url= ""

Comment: Where is your `XML` located and `what is your `Host`?

Comment: it is in my root folder in my project

Comment: I see the length is 0 console.log($xml.length);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `find('bid')` like,

```
 goldBid = $(this).find('bid').text();
```

in place of

```
 goldBid = $(this).attr('Gold Canadian $').children('bid').text();
```

Try this,

```
$xml.find('XAGCAD').each(function () {
    var goldBid, silverBid;
    goldBid = $(this).find('bid').text();
    alert(goldBid);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JG8ug/)